# Programming mobile application with java or c#

Tags: java, c#, android, ios, xamarin

I know java and c# ,i want to learn programming mobile application, but I am confuse between two options:
1. programming with java
2. programming with Xamarin and c#

of course I know with Xamarin  I can programming application for android,IOS and windows phone ,but java is just for android application.

do you hava any idea about this?!!

Comment: Java is for Android. For what I know, you can program in c# on unity, which can then be transformed to either iOS or Android.

Comment: If you are just going for a mobile App for android,go with java is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with Java and Learn Android Programming. Once you master that then go for IOS and windows. I did the same way and now I am working on cross platforms. This helped me out to understand the differences between all mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Java is meant for andriod and works best, c# not so sure. For IOS java is not supported but instead c, c++ and objective-c. c++ is also android. So really c++ if you want to work for both platforms.

Comment: that is probally the best way for you then.

Answer (score 0):

Java for programming will give u the skill set to program for Android, i.e. with the Android SDK.

Using Xamarin you can program apps for iOS, Android and Windows phone under a single platform using solely C#, as opposed to using a separate language and tool for each.

Xamarin is great to learn if you want to deploy on all platforms, but if you're a beginner on mobile development I suggest starting with Java programming and taking it from there.